# Regex in javascript for the url formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like `http://store.mydomain.net/anyname-s/anyname.htm` and also with `www` like `http://www.mydomain.net/anyname-s/anyname.htm`

so what i want to do is to use a wild card * in regex so the * will be anything in the URL like this `http://\*.mydomain.net/\*-s/*.htm`

Asterisk(*) means there it can be any value. and -s is coming at the end of every folder/category name

Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly it is you want, but try this:

```
/http:\/\/(store|www)\.mydomain\.net\/[^\/]+-s.+\.htm/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vouk

Comment: `[^\/]` should probably also exclude `?` and `#`.  The whole regex should probably start with a `^` so it doesn't match `http://evil.org/#http://store.mydomain.net/...`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Sure thing. However, the OP has not specified to what end he wants to use this regex, so I have no idea what other preventive measures to take. I merely gave him the starting point to his adventure into [the very roughly paved] regex land!

Comment: I think it's safe to assume the user does not want to match `http://evil.org/#http://store.mydomain.net/...`

Comment: it worked as expected both of you Joseph and Mike you both gave me new ideas :)

Comment: it is just matching the url as i expected ! i tried to match [http://evil.org/#http://store.mydomain.net/anyname-s/anyname.htm] it did not gave a match for this...

Comment: @JosephSilber yes i checked that sorry ! it "does" but thats what i have no problem with ! as there could be some parameters after .htm like .htm?id=2&val=someval so i changed it now according to my need :) and Mike Samuel yes you were right sorry i was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902256/20394

> Don't try to tailor a regular expression. It will be unmaintainable -- if you can't find the problem with it today, what hope does the maintainer have to find a problem with it tomorrow?

Follow that link for an example of how to solve your problem in a more maintainable way.